# Partition train / test data with np.random.rand

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand this line of code:

```
msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8
```

From my understanding, `numpy.random.rand(len(df))` returns an array of numbers between [0, 1), generated from the uniform distribution.

What does each number represent in the array? Are the values percentiles of the data?

After doing that, we get array of boolean objects, then create train, test sets.

```
train = cdf[msk]
test = cdf[~msk]
```

In this code, for each column in `cdf` is it matching each boolean object in an array `msk` and if it is `True`, it takes that row and put it into `train`? and if `False` into `test` set?

I want to know if my understanding is correct

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. Have you looked at `msk` at all? It is _not_ an array of numbers. Also, `rand` draws from a uniform distribution, not a normal one.

Comment: I ran msk and it gives that array of boolean objects.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `scikit-learn` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed); on the other hand, one would certainly expect a Numpy-related question to be tagged with, well, `numpy`...

Answer (score 6):

`np.random.rand(len(df))` randomly samples `len(df)` floating point numbers from the uniform (0, 1) distribution. Sampling from this distribution generates numbers between 0 and 1.

`msk` is a boolean array.

`msk[i]` is `True` if the `i`-th value randomly generated by `np.random.rand` is less than (<) `0.8`.

`msk[i]` is `False` if the `i`-th value randomly generated by `np.random.rand` is greater than or equal to (>=) `0.8`.

`~msk` flips `True` to `False` and `False` to `True`. With this, the values of `cdf` where `msk` is `True` are assigned to the array `train`, and the values of `cdf` where `msk` is `False` are assigned to `test`.

With this set-up you'd expect approximately 80% of `cdf` to be partitioned into `train`, and the remaining ~20% to be partitioned into `test`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. could you explain what the numbers that are returned from np.random.rand(10) represent?

Comment: You're welcome. ```np.random.rand(10)``` will return 10 randomly generated (floating point) numbers between 0 and 1, where all values are equally likely to be chosen.

Comment: but what does the numbers between 0and 1 represent? within 10 random numbers doesn't have to add up to 1?

Comment: The numbers don't represent anything, they are just that: numbers! The numbers don't have to sum to 1 (you're thinking of probabilities).

Comment: I see. Thanks!!

Comment: I think the numbers could be less than or greater than 80% as these are randomly generated, right ? so we can't be sure if it is 80% exact.

Comment: yep, because we rely on random number generation to perform the partitioning, we won't always get an exact 80:20 split. However, the more data we have, the closer we'll get to the 80:20 split.

Answer (score 0):

`np.random.rand(len(df))` =>
In summary, the above line of code is just a selection criteria generator where the length of df is used to generate random values between 0 and 1.

`msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8` =>
`msk` returns a Boolean array where the random values less than 0.8 are true and vice versa.

`train = cdf[msk]` => This would return the cdf data frame index where `msk` value is True,

`test = cdf[~msk]` => This would return the cdf data frame index where `msk` value is False,
thus splitting the data frame cdf into training data(80%) and test-data(20%)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yMew.png)